# Logger is not working in SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring, logging

I have declared Logger in my class, but I cann't see its output when I run my code on Tomcat - Eclipse.

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
public class TestClassDao implements TestDao{
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    public void deleteData(){
        //Do Operation
        logger.info("Deleted rows affected: " + result);
    }
```

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

When I run the code on Eclipse Kelper using Tomcat Server 7, I am not able to see any output of the logger function.

Can you please suggest what I am missing here?

Comment: Do you actually have a log configuration?

Comment: @chrylis - Yup! due to some requirement, I need to do.

Comment: have you configured log4j.xml with the correct appender. logging does not have anything to do with eclipse. may be some issue with configuration

Answer (score 0):

1. verify you have log4j configuration file (log4j.properties/log4j.xml) in classpath
2. In eclipse, double click your server to open configuration tab
3. Click 'Open launch Configuration'
4. In 'Arguments' tab, add log4j.debug=true to VM arguments

On starting tomcat check the console messages logged by log4j